# Need Spring kafka custom logging

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a standard spring kafka setup as follows,

```
@Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> feedbackStreamListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
```

```
@KafkaListener(topics = ("my-topic"),groupId = ("groupId"),containerFactory = "listenerContainerFactory")
    public void myListener(@Payload String message) {
        System.out.println("Received Message : " + message);
        // do some heavy processing
    }
```

Now I need to have custom logging (generate logs from my app) on 3 scenarios,

1. When I boot the consumer lets say the kafka cluster is down or I provided the wrong bootstrap server, I need to custom log it.
2. When the consumer starts successfully, just before polling provide a custom log.
3. When there is a custom message converter, and if there is a deserialisation issue, custom log it.

Comment: 1) this already gets logged as an error 3) You need to add an exception handler 2) not sure, but sounds like you need to add a lifecycle event to the listener container factory

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `KafkaEvent` implementations: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#events.

So, when you catch `ConsumerFailedToStartEvent` in the `@EventListener`, you can log whatever you want and so on with the `ConsumerStartedEvent`.

There is no even for deserialization issues, but you definitely can use a `GenericErrorHandler` to log something when error from the consumer happens: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#annotation-error-handling

Comment: Hi Artem, thank you for the suggestion. Seems it will work.But the only issue is that, I am stuck with spring kafka verison 2.2.8 version, which dosent have "ConsumerFailedToStartEvent" and "ConsumerStartedEven". It has bunch of other events which I am not sure will suffix. Can we do the same in lower versions of kafka somehow ? Otherwise your suggestion was great.

Comment: Sorry, no. It's not so easy to introduce the logic for those events in the target application. That Spring for Apache Kafka version is out of support for a while already: it would be great if you consider to upgrade your project: https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#learn. Thanks for understanding!